# Mercurial / hg evolve merge changeset switched to wrong branch

Tags: mercurial

I have two named branches `v1` and `v2`.

I merge a new changeset `abc` from `v1` into `v2`. The merge changeset `m` is in branch `v2`.

I notice there's a small typo in `abc`.
In `v1` I amend `abc` -> `abc'`.
I execute `hg evolve` and get a new merge changeset `m'`.

All this is as expected. But now `m'` is in `v1` instead of `v2`. That is unexpected and not what I want.

What should I have done different? What can I do to fix this now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed it sounds unexpected and you probably should report that very issue to the evolve developers.

On the matter at hand: You can manually merge `m'` into v2, and manually obsolete or strip the unneeded changesets.

EDIT to add: If you want to fix it in-place, you can resort to the debug commands. Check out `hg help debug`. Use them with great care and only when you have a full copy of the repo. I haven't tried, but maybe `hg debugsetparents` can be of utility.